# Push XML DATA to REST API with PHP/cURL/JSON

Tags: php, json, xml, php-curl, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm somewhat stuck on a problem. I'm attempting to write an app that basically reads and sorts DATA from an online XML file containing customers and recreates those customers in Wordpress/woocommerce through cURL/php/JSON. I'm using insomnia to test my calls and code pieces.

This is what I got so far:

1. Pull customer data from the online database into xml [ but its raw unsorted and too much info ]
2. Create a customer in Woocommerce/ Wordpress by POST request in JSON/PHP/cURL

Im currently missing the bridge between sorting the XML data into a table and having that data be filled into a piece of code containing variables that recreates said data into woocommerce through REST API.

---

Shortly said, I want to:

1. Pull Customer data into XML - OK
2. Read the XML customer data and assign it to variables
3. Use said variables to push and recreate customers in Woocommerce/wordpress.

How should I approach this ?

This is how I create a customer in woocommerce. Basically the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` tags should contain a single line from that customer XML table with its assign data.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&consumer_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"email\": \"john.doe@example.com\",\n  \"first_name\": \"John\",\n  \"last_name\": \"Doe\",\n  \"username\": \"john.doe\",\n  \"billing\": {\n    \"first_name\": \"John\",\n    \"last_name\": \"Doe\",\n    \"company\": \"\",\n    \"address_1\": \"969 Market\",\n    \"address_2\": \"\",\n    \"city\": \"San Francisco\",\n    \"state\": \"CA\",\n    \"postcode\": \"94103\",\n    \"country\": \"US\",\n    \"email\": \"john.doe@example.com\",\n    \"phone\": \"(555) 555-5555\"\n  },\n  \"shipping\": {\n    \"first_name\": \"John\",\n    \"last_name\": \"Doe\",\n    \"company\": \"\",\n    \"address_1\": \"969 Market\",\n    \"address_2\": \"\",\n    \"city\": \"San Francisco\",\n    \"state\": \"CA\",\n    \"postcode\": \"94103\",\n    \"country\": \"US\"\n  }\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Basic Og==",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

The JSON in insomania has these as input, same story as above, it should be filled with the customer data form the XML:

```
{
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "username": "john.doe",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of the response from the XML data. I've expanded account code 2 to show its contents. Obviously I don't want everything from it, I'm only interested in name, email, address, phone and VAT number for instance.

```
<eExact
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">
  <Accounts>
    <Account code="0" searchcode="" status="A" ID="{2723dc8f-33d0-XXXX-9710-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">
        </Account>
    <Account code="1" searchcode="" status="A" ID="{7c6f362c-79e1-XXXX-8822-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">
        </Account>
    <Account code="2" searchcode="" status="C" ID="{132c9c6b-dd66-XXXX-b276-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">
      <Name>BOB</Name>
      <Phone>6845641564564654156454</Phone>
      <PhoneExt />
      <Fax />
      <Email>example@example.com</Email>
      <HomePage>example.com<</HomePage>
      <Language code="EN" />
      <IsSupplier>1</IsSupplier>
      <CanDropShip>0</CanDropShip>
      <IsBlocked>0</IsBlocked>
      <IsReseller>0</IsReseller>
      <IsSales>1</IsSales>
      <IsPurchase>1</IsPurchase>
      <ShowRemarkForSales>0</ShowRemarkForSales>
      <Contact number="2090075" gender="M" default="1" ID="{2449ce5d-41b3-XXXX-bab3-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">
        <LastName>BOB</LastName>
        <MiddleName />
        <BirthName>BOB</BirthName>
        <BirthNamePrefix />
        <PartnerName />
        <PartnerNamePrefix />
        <FirstName>BOB</FirstName>
        <Initials />
        <Language code="SAMPLE" />
        <Phone>44546456456e</Phone>
        <PhoneExt />
        <Fax />
        <Mobile>eeeeeeeeeeeeeee</Mobile>
        <Email>example@example.com</Email>
        <BirthPlace />
        <IsMailingExcluded>0</IsMailingExcluded>
        <Job>
          <Description>role</Description>
        </Job>
        <IsAnonymised>0</IsAnonymised>
      </Contact>
      <Address type="TES" default="1" ID="{41bde841-afde-XXXX-9cd0-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">
        <AddressLine1>sampleroad</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2 />
        <AddressLine3 />
        <PostalCode>1000000</PostalCode>
        <City>Appels</City>
        <State code="O-V" />
        <Country code="EN" />
        <Phone />
        <Fax />
        <Contact number="2090075" ID="{2449ce5d-41b3-XXXX-bab3-XXXXXXXXXXXX}" />
      </Address>
      <VATNumber>VATXXXXXXXX</VATNumber>
      <VATLiability>L</VATLiability>
      <GovernmentVATSystem>0</GovernmentVATSystem>
      <ChamberOfCommerce />
      <ChamberOfCommerceEstablishment />
      <GlnNumber />
      <SalesCurrency code="EUR" />
      <PurchaseCurrency code="EUR" />
      <CreditLine>
        <Sales>0</Sales>
        <Purchase>0</Purchase>
      </CreditLine>
      <Discount>
        <SalesPercentage>0.9</SalesPercentage>
        <PurchasePercentage>0</PurchasePercentage>
      </Discount>
      <AccountClassifications />
      <IsMailing>0</IsMailing>
      <IsCompetitor>0</IsCompetitor>
      <StartDate>2020-11-25</StartDate>
      <IntraStat>
        <System />
        <TransactionA />
        <TransactionB />
        <TransportMethod />
        <DeliveryTerm />
        <Area />
      </IntraStat>
      <InvoicingMethod>0</InvoicingMethod>
      <IsAnonymised>0</IsAnonymised>
    </Account>
  </Accounts>
  <Topics>
    <Topic code="Accounts" ts_d="XXXXXXXXXXXX" count="3" pagesize="1000" />
  </Topics>
  <Messages />
</eExact>
```

Comment: Parse the XML to an object, and then encode the object to JSON. Have you tried anything specific?

Comment: P.S. "Pull customer data from the online database into xml"...does it have to be XML? Does that database not output anything else? e.g. could it return JSON directly? Just putting that out there in case the process could be simplified, but obviously I don't know anything about that system and what access you have or what you can get from it.

Comment: @ADyson, it can export as .csv aswell but i reckon thats even harder to work with than xml... Haven't tried anything specific yet.

Comment: It's probably harder if you have a nested data structure, which it looks like you have..so yeah maybe stick to XML. You should be able to find tutorials etc already which explain how to parse XML using PHP. Give it a try. If you then get stuck, ask us something more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an array structure from the XML using DOM+Xpath and serialize it to JSON. Xpath expressions allow you to fetch node list and scalar values from the DOM using location paths and conditions.

For example:

- any `Account`
  `/eExact/Accounts/Account`
- that has the `status` `C`
  `/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C"]`
- just the last node
  `(/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C"])[last()]`

The `/` at the start of the location path anchors it to the document otherwise the expression will use the current context (the second argument of `DOMXpath::evaluate()`).

For example:

- any `Email` child element
  `Email`
- cast first found `Email` to string
  `string(Email)`

Demo:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);

$json = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/eExact/Accounts/Account[@status="C"])[last()]') as $account) {
    $json['email'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Email)', $account);
    $json['username'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $account);
    $json['first_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account);
    $json['last_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account);
    $json['billing'] = [
      'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
      'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
      'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
    ];
    // ...
}
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "username": "BOB",
    "first_name": "BOB",
    "last_name": "BOB",
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "BOB",
        "last_name": "BOB",
        "postcode": "1000000"
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getXML(), is this because something else needs to be defined/initiated in the code or is this a config problem in xamp. Im using xampp on windows to run the php code.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to replace the getXML function with my $response parameter since thats where my xml is the output