# PHP - JSON encode output contains only 1 XML entry instead of multiple

Tags: php, json, xml, php-curl

**UPDATE:**

Previous post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291311/push-xml-data-to-rest-api-with-php-curl-json/65307356)

Ok so I got the code working perfectly for 1 customer. Now i ran into another problem if i wanna recieve multiple customers as JSON output , how would i do that ?

I've created a second entry under accounts with status C and modified the code parts i've recieved so far to basically output name/email/... from all accounts with status C. However im only recieving the first one it sees. Probably made a mistake somewhere

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($response);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);

$json = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/eExact/Accounts)') as $account) {
    $json['email'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Email)', $account);
    
    $json['first_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account);
    $json['last_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account);
    $json['billing'] = [
      'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
      'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
      'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
    ];

    // ...
}

$customer = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $customer;
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "email": "example1@example1.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "postcode": "10000"
    }
}[Finished in 0.4s]
```

---

What i actually would want is something like this: [or in other words all status C accounts ]

```
 {
        "email": "example1@example1.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "postcode": "10000"
        }
 {
        "email": "example2@example2.com",
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "Steve",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "postcode": "20000"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$json` array keys with each iteration. You made it a one-dimensional array and what you need is a multidimensional array (where each element is another array):

```php
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/eExact/Accounts)') as $account) {
    $json[] = [
        'email' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Email)', $account),
        'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
        'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
        'billing' => [
            'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
            'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
            'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
        ],
    ];
}
```

The key here is `$json[] = ...` - this tells PHP to create a new element in the array and assign it the value that follows.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating one array and overwriting it each time through the loop.  There are multiple ways to append, but with existing code you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/eExact/Accounts)') as $account) {
    $json['email'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Email)', $account);        
    $json['first_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account);
    $json['last_name'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account);
    $json['billing'] = [
      'first_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/FirstName)', $account),
      'last_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Contact[@default="1"]/LastName)', $account),
      'postcode'=> $xpath->evaluate('string(Account[@status="C"]/Address[@default="1"]/PostalCode)', $account),
    ];
    // append to your result here
    $result[] = $json;
}
$customer = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $customer;
```